# WPF resetting DataContext to refresh binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a project that gets data from a database and binds that data to some elements in xaml. I have added a button that fetches new data from the database and want to refresh the data bound elements in the xaml.

Now, I know the proper way of doing this is to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged events in the data class but I wanted to avoid this as there are so many properties. I figured out that simply calling 'this.DataContext = data;' after I have retrieved the new data from the database updates the binding in xaml.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, if you don't want to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, then don't use WPF. WPF is quite often a verbose language... it took me a while to get used to this. While there are mechanisms like `Converter`s, `Style`s and `Attached Properties` that enable us to reuse code, you will often find yourself writing code that you've written before. Just get used to it, or change languages.

To summarise, you can't write effective applications in WPF without implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface you don't allow the binding mechanism to work since it wont know of any changes of your data.
The data binding is one of the most powerful tools in WPF if you dont use it you will have to write the propagation of the data changes between you model and the UI yourself  like it was done in `Winforms`....

if its too hard to write the implementation for each property of each class in your than you can create a code snippet.. like prop/propdp